# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 7

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

> (main method calling classes)
>
> ```
> import java.io.*;
>
> public class bob {
> public static void main(String[] args){
>     new bert();
>   new larry();
> ```
>
> (creates a file and copys string to it)
>
> ```
> public class larry{
>   bert bertObj = new bert();
>   public larry(){
>       try{
>       File file = new File("text.txt");
>
>       if(!file.exists())
>           file.createNewFile();
>       PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
>       for(String x: bertObj.string){
>       pw.println(x);
>       }
>       pw.close();
>   }catch(IOException e){
>       e.printStackTrace();
>   }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> (reads a file and copies it into a string array) 
>      (i havent initialised the string, i think that maybe the error, though i dont know how many values i will be storing inside it so i do not wish to do            String string[] = new String[100] for example.... what else can i do?)
>
> ```
> public class bert {
>   String string[];
>   public bert(){
>       BufferedReader br = null;
>       try{
>           br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_101\\THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt"));
>           int counter = 0;
>           while((string[counter] = br.readLine()) != null)
>           {
>               counter++;
>           }
>           for(int x = counter; x < 4000; x++)
>               string[x] = "";
>       }catch(IOException e){
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       }finally{
>           try {
>               br.close();
>           } catch (IOException e) {
>               e.printStackTrace();
>           }
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: The simplest solution to this is to get rid of arrays and use an ArrayList or Strings.  I do not know what you think `for(int x = counter; x < 4000; x++)
              string[x] = "";` will do

Answer (score -1):

In class bert, your String[] is never initialized before you try to access it in this line:

```
while((string[counter] = br.readLine()) != null)
```

Just like you initialized bert in the larry class, you need to initialize the String[] in the bert class.

Turn this line:

```
String [] string;
```

Into:

```
String[] string = new String[5];  // 5 is an arbitrary number I chose, you need to choose how many strings you will be holding in that array
```

Sorry, did not fully read your comments.  Instead of a static array, try using an arraylist.  This does not work the same as an array.

To give you a short example:

```
ArrayList<String> string = new ArrayList();
string.add("hello");     // string now has a string "hello"
string.add("world");     // string now has a string "hello" followed by a string "world"

for(int i = 0; i < string.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(string.get(i));  // gets position i from the array and prints it.  Will print hello then a new line then world.
}
```

More on the arraylist here:

[ArrayList API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: Thanks man! Very helpful :)

Comment: No problem, I hate when people mark as duplicate, just answer the question, these are sometimes very specific!